# Qt работа со строками

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

Не получается распарсить строку на подстроки.
Например есть строка:
"1k" qqq "2" "U2" h "h4"

Как вывести построки, выделенные в кавычки "*", чтобы получить:
1k
2
U2
h4

Не удалось реализовать самостоятельно.

Comment: Укажите метку языка

Comment: Расскажите подробнее о формате строк. Всегда ли слова разделены одним пробелом? Могут ли быть не только обрамляющиеся слова кавычки?

Comment: Только кавычки и всегда пробелами. Но могут быть символы не в кавычках, как, например, qqq. Их учитывать не надо

Comment: Я имею в виду, может ли быть `qq"qq`?

Comment: Нет, такого не может быть. Строки форматированы. Проблема решена. Снизу решение подошло. Спасибо вам за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в строке всегда разделение пробелами, то можно сначала получить список всех подстрок, а потом каждый элемент списка проверить на наличие кавычек.

```
QString s = "1k" qqq "2" "U2" h "h4";
QStringList paths = s.split(" ");
for(QString res : paths){
 if(res.contains("\"")){
   qDebug() << res;
 }
}
```

Либо воспользоваться QRegExp, если условия не так однозначны.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Решение подошло.

Comment: @Alin поставьте галку слева от него тогда